# Unable to find Rasa custom component

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa

I am trying to add a custom component in Rasa.
After writing my custom component when I tried to train my model, I got the following errors:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RasaCustomPy'
```

and

```
Exception: Failed to find component class for 'RasaCustomPy.my_module.MyCustomComponent'. Unknown component name. Check your configured pipeline and make sure the mentioned component is not misspelled. If you are creating your own component, make sure it is either listed as part of the `component_classes` in `rasa.nlu.registry.py` or is a proper name of a class in a module.
```

My project has the following structure:

```
RasaCustomPy
|
|---__init__.py
|
|---actions.py
|
|---my_module.py
|
|---data
|
|---venv
|
|---config.yml
|
|---credentials.yml
|
|---domain.yml
|
|---endpoints.yml
```

Inside `config.yml`, I have tried to add my custom component as follows:

```
pipeline: 
- name: RasaCustomPy.my_module.MyCustomComponent
```

All Rasa dependency packages are installed inside the `venv` folder.
I get the error when I tried to train it using the command `rasa train` after activating my virtualenv. I am using Rasa 1.0.7.

I am new to Rasa and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue of custom component paths not being correctly added to the python path was fixed in 1.1.5, so make sure that you have a version that is later than that one (in general including your version of whatever software you're running in SO posts is helpful for anyone trying to debug/replicate your issue)

The paths should be relative to where your config is located, so in this case, as you're already in the RasaCustomPy directory, I think you want

```
pipeline: 
 - name: my_module.MyCustomComponent
```

but if that doesn't work, try playing around with the path to the file.

Comment: Indeed it was the older version I was using. After updating rasa to latest, custom component got recognized. Thanks.

Comment: I also changed the name of the component in pipeline as described by you.